# Load Vim plugin after file

Tags: vim

I am implementing [Plain Text/Source Code File Header](http://www.synchro.net/draft-swindell-ptsc-hdr-01.txt) for Vim and I need my parser to run after the file, since it needs the first 60 lines of the buffer. I successfully made a *manual* parser, but it needs me to run `call PtScParse()` on each buffer by hand. Is there a way to make `PtScParse()` automatically run on each buffer?

My parser is [on this DARCS repo](http://darcsden.com/karl/vim-ptsc-header). Look for the `ptsc-header.vim` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the documentation in `:help initialization` and `:help :autocmd` I found my solution. All
I had to do was to add the following line at the end of the script:

```
autocmd VimEnter * call PtScHeaderParse()
```

It calls `PtScHeaderParse()`  on all files on event `VimEnter`.
Now every time I open a file, the function runs and shows my code properly :)